# django tastypie foreignkey in different django application

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I am trying to from another application's model whose foreign key is referenced in the current app. This is what the `model.py` looks like.

```
class DataQuestion(models.Model):
    ...
    PollF = models.ForeignKey('myapp2.PollF')
```

If I try to use this in tasypie, I get a `null` value. This is what my `api.py` looks like.

```
from myapp2.models import DataQuestion

class HelperSurveyResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = DataQuestion.objects.all()
        resource_name='some_name'
        ...
    def dehydrate(self,bundle):
        bundle.data['complete']=True if(bundle.obj.isPComplete) else False
        return bundle

class QnResource(ModelResource):
    pollF=fields.ForeignKey(HelperSurveyResource,'some_name',full=True,null=True)

class Meta:
    queryset=DataQuestion.objects.all()
```

This is the result I get:

```
{"pollF": null,
"numAnswers": 1,
....
"text": "How much do you earn per day?"},
```

What can I do to get a non-null value? Any help? Thanks

---------EDIT---------
Question got anwsered on the IRC. Thanks a lot `Funkybob` The mistake was that 'some_name' was supposed to be `pollF`.

Comment: Can you please post this answer to answer here and mark it as correct answer?

Comment: @JureC.done :D added answer. can accept it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

For Jure C. Here's the answer:

```
from myapp2.models import DataQuestion

class HelperSurveyResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = DataQuestion.objects.all()
        resource_name='some_name'
        ...
    def dehydrate(self,bundle):
        bundle.data['complete']=True if(bundle.obj.isPComplete) else False
        return bundle
```

change occurs here -> to PollF It's supposed to be the name of the attribute to search for. I didn't know this

```
class QnResource(ModelResource):
    pollF=fields.ForeignKey(HelperSurveyResource,'pollF',full=True,null=True)

class Meta:
    queryset=DataQuestion.objects.all()
```